# Decidable Program Equivalence

Tags: complexity-theory, computability

Determining whether two programs always return same output for same input is undecidable (easily reduced to the halting problem). My question is, is there a complexity class in which this problem is decidable for machines on that class?

Seems like it must be below PTIME, as Datalog is P-Complete and equivalence of Datalog programs is undecidable.

Comment: What do you mean by "complexity class"? Does the class of regular languages count as one, for instance? Note that not all complexity classes have a machine model that correspond to them.

Comment: Your question contains a category error. Complexity classes are classes of problems (e.g., "Is this graph 3-colourable"), not classes of programs (e.g., algorithms which may or may not compute 3-colourings of graphs").

Comment: they're classes of programs too - all machines that run in say polynomial time wrt the input size. im just talking from descriptive complexity point of view

Comment: more explicitly and for example, one can take any machine that runs in PTIME and convert it into a datalog program. if we could decide equivalence of any two PTIME machines, then we could decide equivalence of datalog programs. therefore such is undecidable

Answer (score 1):

Given a Turing machine $M$, we can construct another Turing machine $T$, which on input $1^n$ simulates $M$ for $\log n$ steps, and returns whether $M$ halted within these steps. The new Turing machine runs in linear time, and is equivalent to the constant time Turing machine which always returns "No" iff $M$ doesn't halt. Therefore program equivalence is undecidable even for linear time Turing machines.

Comment: sorry but im sure im missing something here. can you please elaborate a little more?

Comment: @TroyMcClure if ive gotten the argument right, Yuval is saying « the turing machine that decides program equivalence could solve the halting problem »

Comment: @TroyMcClure Above $M$ is any arbitrary TM. TM $T$ simultaes $M$ only for $\log n$ steps, so $T$ has linear complexity, no matter what $M$ is. If $M$ does not halt, $T$ will answer "no" to all inputs. If $M$ halts, $T$ will answer "no" for small inputs, and "yes" for large enough inputs. So, if we can decide the equivalence of the linear-time $T$ with the constant time "always no" TM, we decide the halting problem on any $M$.

Comment: but it can solve the halting problem only for M and even that is after we constructed a machine that solves the halting problem for M (so we already know whether M halts). or im missing something

Answer (score 1):

Reversal Bounded Counter Automata have decidable equivalence. They're a fascinating class, because augmenting them in any obvious way makes one of their main properties (equivalence, emptiness, etc.) undecidable.
Oscar Ibarra's work explored their properties extensively: http://www.lsv.ens-cachan.fr/~demri/Ibarra78.pdf

If I recall correctly, visibly pushdown Automata also have decidable equivalence, though I'm as familiar with that class.

Comment: what can we tell about their expressive power?

Comment: @TroyMcClure They're not comparable with Context Free languages i.e. more powerful in some respects, weaker in others. I think in the unary case they're equivalent to Presburger arithmetic, but I don't remember the reference for that offhand.

Comment: thanks, so it doesn't correspond to any standard complexity class?

Comment: @TroyMcClure the class accepted by the deterministic variant at least is a subset of P.